# The tickers used in pandas morningstar API

Tags: python, pandas-datareader

Here is what I done for obtaining the price of the stock "TSLA" using the DataReader with morningstar API

```
import pandas_datareader.data as web
df = web.DataReader('TSLA', 'morningstar', start, end)
```

However, if I input a wrong ticker for the first parameter of the creator of DataReader, Python just keep running the line.

How to check whether a ticker is input correctly for the first parameter?

Answer (score 1):

When I ran your code with an invalid ticker symbol, I experienced the same problem with the Python Interpreter just hanging.  I didn't find an entirely neat solution, but based on a somewhat related issue report I read on github ([link here](https://github.com/pydata/pandas-datareader/issues/513)), I've come up with an answer that will stop the python interpreter from hanging if you enter an invalid ticker symbol.

The key seems to be setting the `retry_count` parameter of `pandas_datareader.data.DataReader()` equal to zero.

I have a fully reproducible snippet below:

```
import pandas_datareader
import datetime

start = datetime.datetime(2018, 5, 1)
end = datetime.datetime(2018, 5, 30)

def get_data(ticker):
    try:
        df = pandas_datareader.data.DataReader('%s' % (ticker), 'morningstar', start, end, retry_count=0)
        print(df.tail(5))
    except ValueError:
        print('Ticker Symbol %s is not available!' % (ticker))

get_data('TSLA') #valid Symbol
get_data('yyfy') #not a valid Symbol
get_data('AAPL') #valid Symbol
get_data('QQQQ') #not a valid Symbol
```

With Expected Output:

```
Symbol Date        Close     High     Low      Open   Volume
TSLA   2018-05-24  277.85  281.110  274.89  278.4000  4190598
       2018-05-25  278.85  279.640  275.61  277.6252  3875082
       2018-05-28  278.85  278.850  278.85  278.8500        0
       2018-05-29  283.76  286.500  276.15  278.5100  5666640
       2018-05-30  291.72  295.005  281.60  283.2900  7428352

Ticker Symbol yyfy is not available!

Symbol Date        Close    High     Low    Open    Volume
AAPL   2018-05-24  188.15  188.84  186.21  188.77  20330134
       2018-05-25  188.58  189.65  187.65  188.23  17460963
       2018-05-28  188.58  188.58  188.58  188.58         0
       2018-05-29  187.90  188.75  186.87  187.60  22514075
       2018-05-30  187.50  188.00  186.78  187.72  18430891

Ticker Symbol QQQQ is not available!
```

Comment: Thanks, that was a great tip. `retry_count` and `ValueError` made it work for me.