# Pandas Datareader with Morningstar

Tags: python, pandas, web-scraping, error-handling, timer

I'm web scraping with pandas and using morningstar's API. Every now and then I scrape a website with a ticker that morningstar struggles with and crashes python.

I've included relevant lines below and it almost always work and I don't think my code is causing the errors but I can't get around pandas freezing up on me. Date is a variable here that is in the correct format for DataReader, it doesn't raise problems.

```
import pandas as pd
import pandas_datareader.data as web

df = web.DataReader(ticker, "morningstar", date)
```

If a ticker is getting stuck, after a couple minutes pandas will print (on it's own, not my print statement) the phrase "adding (insert ticker here) to retry list". Shortly after the message pops up I get a pop up window saying "Python quit unexpectedly".

I've tried to wrap the datareader in a while loop with a timer to stop it and move on to the next ticker but it didn't work. I'm assuming this is because of control flow.
I've also tried to use the interruptingcow module in hopes it could help but got the same result as a regular timer.

Is there a way to get around this? It crashes my script every time.
Some tickers I've come across that are a pain are 'BBXTB', 'CRXPF', 'IMMVD', and 'FFRMF'

Answer (score 1):

I still do not know exactly why the tickers would fail and am investigating. however, I was able to allow the failure to not crash the scripts by directly modifying `pandas_datareader\mstar\daily.py`.

My version is `0.6.0`. The instructions are for this version only.

lines 134 - 138 looks like this:

```
if len(failed) > 0 and self.retry_count > 0:
    # TODO: This appears to do nothing since
    # TODO: successful symbols are not added to
    self._dl_mult_symbols(symbols=failed)
    self.retry_count -= 1
```

the counter is in the wrong place and needs to be swapped with the above line, as such:

```
if len(failed) > 0 and self.retry_count > 0:
    # TODO: This appears to do nothing since
    # TODO: successful symbols are not added to
    self.retry_count -= 1
    self._dl_mult_symbols(symbols=failed)
```

this should allow the failed call to exit gracefully without causing a stack overflow.

incidentally, https://github.com/pydata/pandas-datareader/blob/master/pandas_datareader/mstar/daily.py shows that @dtemkin has directly fixed the current build of pandas_datareader so this may be released/resolved on next release.

You can find this file by locating where python stores its libraries. I installed anaconda through Visual Studio 2017, and the location of the file is at: `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Anaconda3_64\lib\site-packages\pandas_datareader\mstar\daily.py`

Answer (score 1):

I think your question is on the similar lines of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50478715/the-tickers-used-in-pandas-morningstar-api#).

Below snippet should help:

```
import pandas_datareader
import datetime

start = datetime.datetime(2018, 5, 1)
end = datetime.datetime(2018, 5, 30)

def get_data(ticker):
    try:
        df = pandas_datareader.data.DataReader('%s' % (ticker), 'morningstar', start, end, retry_count=0)
        print(df.tail(5))
    except ValueError:
     print('Ticker Symbol %s is not available!' % (ticker))

get_data('TSLA') #valid Symbol
get_data('yyfy') #not a valid Symbol
```

The `retry_count` and `ValueError` made it work for me.

Answer (score 0):

Until 0.7.0 is released, it is advisable to download the latest development version of Pandas Datareader from the master branch of the [Github repository](https://github.com/pydata/pandas-datareader). If you're using [pip](https://pypi.org/project/pip/), I would recommend:

```
$ pip install git+https://github.com/pydata/pandas-datareader
```

Answer (score 0):

According to data reader docs, Yahoo!, Google Options, Google Quotes and EDGAR have been immediately deprecated due to large changes in their API and no stable replacement. Use 'iex' instead

```
import pandas_datareader.data as web
import datetime as dt    

start = dt.datetime(2018,1,1)
end = dt.datetime(2019,1,1)

aapl = web.DataReader('AAPL', 'iex', start, end)

aapl.shape
(251, 5)

aapl.head()

    open    high    low close   volume
date                    
2018-01-02  167.6431    169.7514    166.7564    169.7120    25555934
2018-01-03  169.9780    171.9682    169.4165    169.6825    29517899
2018-01-04  169.9879    170.9041    169.5347    170.4707    22434597
2018-01-05  170.8746    172.7760    170.4904    172.4115    23660018
2018-01-08  171.7711    173.0125    171.3573    171.7711    20567766
```